# std::exp giving different result than MATLAB exp for complex number

Tags: c++, matlab, complex-numbers, exp

I'm copying a script from matlab into a c++ function. However, I constantly get different result for the exp function. For example, following snippet:

```
std::complex<double> final_b = std::exp(std::complex<double>(0, 1 * pi));
```

should be equivalent to the MATLAB code

```
final_b = exp(1i * pi);
```

But it isn't. For MATLAB, I receive -1 + 0i (which is correct) and for c++, I get -1 + -2.068231e-013*i.

Now I thought at the beginning this is just a rounding error of sorts, but for the actual script I'm using, which has bigger complex exponentials, I get completely different numbers. What is the cause of this? How do I fix this?

Edit: I've manually tried calculating the exponential with eulers formula

```
exp(x+iy) = exp(x) * (cos(y) + i*sin(y))
```

and get the same wonky results in c++

Comment: Are you familiar with the term floating point precision?

Comment: @40two judging by the content of the question, I think the answer is yes.

Comment: just an idea, did you check the precision of pi?

Comment: It's not guaranteed that MatLab and C++ are computing the `exp` in the same manner. Thus, a small round-off error is tolerable. Have in mind that in the background calculating trigonometric functions like `cos` and `sin` involves iterative procedures like `Newton-Raphson` etc. Please state the amound of error you are getting in-order for us to have a more clear picture of your problem. P.S state also how you are printing those values.

Comment: Turns out you are right 40two. I've been reading the results wrong...whenever MATLAB outputs 0, C++ outputs something very close to 0. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is called floating point approximation (or *imprecision*):

If you include the header `cfloat` there are some definitions. In particular, `DBL_EPSILON`, which is the smallest number that `1.0 + DBL_EPSILON != 1.0`, which is usually `1e-9` (and `-2.068231e-013` is **much** smaller than that. If you do the following piece of code, you can check if it is zero or not:

```
// The complete formula is std::abs(a - b), but since b is zero, I am ommiting it
if (std::abs(number.imag()) < DBL_EPSILON) {
    // The number is either zero or very close to zero
}
```

For example, you can see the working code here: http://ideone.com/2OzNZm

Comment: Just a note on a detail: DBL_EPSILON is 2.2204460492503131e-016 in my float.h. Idem in Matlab ... maybe you are confusing with FLT_EPSILON, which is about 1.192092896e-07 usually. Beside that tiny detail, it is a good explanation.

Comment: Would just simply checking if the number is smaller than DBL_EPSILON and then rounding to zero suffice?

Comment: @Bentoy13 correct, that value depends on libc implementation and might (I am not sure) depend on compiler flags.

Comment: @BananaCode In fact, that is the correct way to do. Let me fix the code.

Comment: Uhm, DBL_EPSILON is the minimum value that summed to `1.0` produces a different value (i.e. it's a measure of the granularity of `double`), how is it related to the precision of the result of trigonometric/exponential functions?

Comment: If you check [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e+%5E+%28i+*+pi%29&lk=4&num=1), the result should be `-1 + 0i` or simply `-1`. But the result is something that is not zero, but really close to it, when doing that calculation using the standard C++ api, that is why it is related to the imprecision of floating point numbers.